# Can't use Ethernet or Wifi in Ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, server, wireless, sudo

This is my first time using Ubuntu Server (16.04 i386) and it has not started out well at all.

Generally, I'm not very good with Linux, and this sounds like the stupidest question in the world, but how do I access the internet?

I can't connect via Ethernet - its not recognising anything. I wanted to connect via Wifi, but I couldn't (because something called rfkill is blocking it). I can't use rfkill to unblock it, because I can't download the package.

I can't even do `sudo apt-get update`.

I never had this problem with Ubuntu desktop - someone please help me urgently!!!!!

## Edit

I cannot use rfkill to *unblock* my wifi adapter because rfkill is not installed, and I can't install it because I can't access the internet!

Comment: I wouldn't have selected 16.04; it's on it's last months of supported life (5 years from 2016-April release), but did you check to see if networking devices are recognized (`sudo lshw -C network` for example to list hardware of class networking). If you got anywhere on the troubleshooting guide with wifi (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TroubleShootingGuide) providing that detail & what you've already attempted (`rfkill` detail for example) may help us to understand where you are in your troubleshooting.

Comment: @guiverc I looked EVERYWHERE and I couldn't find a 32-bit image for anything newer than 16.04. Of course, I would've chosen a newer one *if they didn't make it so hard to find one!*. I used 18.04 desktop earlier. I'll have a look at that troubleshooting guide

Comment: 32bit or i386 images were produced for some *flavors* into the *disco* cycle (19.04), the latest i386 ISO released was 18.04.5 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) though yes fewer i386 images are available (eg. netboot ISO maybe required to install a i386 server)  *Default server installer is not `subiquity` (ie. *live* installer) which is amd64/arm64 only so i386 is alternate ISO only now

Comment: @guiverc That link doesn't seem to show the i386 ISOs for me. When I follow the link to the 18.04 page, it only shows options to download the 64bit

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/bionic/

Comment: Is this in a VM or installed on a system?

Comment: @guiverc HERO! I've never heard of Netboot before, but it was pretty self explanatory and it worked! Everything is fixed! Feel free to write that as an answer and I'm happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: @NicolasHanna It was installed as the only OS on a system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 is the 2016-April release, so is largely limited to kernel modules (*drivers*) of that era. Ubuntu's use of HWE allows you to use an updated software stack (ie. ISOs are available with 16.04 using 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04 kernel & stack) but it's still only parts of the stack updated.

Ubuntu 18.04 provides the full 2018-April release, and likewise it's ISOs are available with different stacks, including 18.10's, 19.04, 19.10 & 20.04 stack. The latter is the most modern being released as the 18.04.5 media.

- http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/

Canonical/Ubuntu is moving away from i386/32-bit, however it was still supported in some releases post 18.04, however they're now EOL. The last media was 18.04.5 and can be found for example at

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/bionic/

Flavored desktops have ISOs too, however Ubuntu Server now uses the `subiquity` or *live* installer, which is 64-bit only so no *live* i386 ISOs exist for later server installs, however netboot installs are still available.

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: This answer doesn't really fit the question, I was tempted to just close as *problem went away*, so I've *blabed* about HWE & ISO install options with some i386/ISO detail thrown in, but all quickly & vague, with links (I do like *official* links)